# Why do technic bushings have a flat side and a wavy side?

Tags: technic

Exhibit <s>A</s> 3713:

[image]

The near side is smooth on the circumference, but the far side has a wavy pattern. In Lego directions, the photos usually show the "orientation" of the bushing, but if I put it on the incorrect way, will it affect the build?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

The answer is **studs**. Note that there are more pieces with the same ability.

[image]

*Orientation of the bushing **does** matter when you run a rotating axle through a technic plate. Have the round side of the bushing pointing towards the studs. Otherwise the axle might lock up.*

---

Here's an example from set 852 where this technique is used to attach the helicopter's rotor and propeller to an axle.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would also add that initially, when Technic was released there were no studless beams. This required for new system to adapt to existing building approach - building studs up. In the end it required new (Technic) plates and adapted bushes to interlock assembly vertically. Later parts (like connectors in the photo) just followed new system.

Comment: @Alex Good point! I've added an example...

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The wavy side allows you to wedge the bush between 4 studs on a plate or brick.

In my experience, placing the bush differently orientated never affects the build.